# How to check query return empty object in MongoEngine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

This is the version I used :

```
pymongo 3.9.0, 
mongoengine-0.18.2,
python 3.7.1
```

I have a simple `Document` like below:

```
class MyModel(Document):
    meta = {"collection": "my_model"}

    name = StringField()
    email = StringField()
    address = StringField()
```

I want to check whether a `record` is exists by using the `name`,`email` or `address` .I follow this [docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html?highlight=contains#advanced-queries)

**Therefore I run this query:**

```
user = MyModel.objects(Q(name="myname") | Q(email="abc@mail.com") | Q(address="1234567"))

if user.count() > 0: 
   print "User Existed"
```

But the result is always return true,which is `User already existed`,even the collection is empty one.

I also tried `if user is None`,but the result is still the same.I think is because it always will return a object whether have result or not.

**So my question is,** how can I check whether a query is returning result or empty result?

Comment: it's `user.objects.count()`

Comment: can u provide an example,cause I get this error `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'`

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I misread the question. Your query looks good and does work as you intend. Just checked it with mongoengine-0.18.2 pymongo-3.10.0 Python 3.7.5

Comment: you mean my query only work with `mongoengine-0.18.2 pymongo-3.10.0 Python 3.7.5` ?

Comment: I mean it is the version I had installed and was using it to make a quick test. I did not check other versions. I would suggest to add versions you are using to the question. It may help others to answer. Evidently it is not reproducible on all  version.

Comment: pymongo 3.9.0, mongoengine-0.18.2,python 3.7.1 this is what i installed

Comment: ok I understand now